# Get xpath on dynamic build page

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, dynamic, scrapy

I am trying to get an xpath of a page that has a dynamic construction according to the number of elements that each one has can have more or less "< li>"

**I need this**

[image: I need this]

**but i get this**

[image: but i get this]

I am trying with text finder:

`//*[contains(text(),"Fecha Publicación:")]/text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `../` or `ancestor::node()[1]` at the end of the code returns to the previous

`//*[contains(text(),"Fecha Publicación:")]/../text()`

or

`//*[contains(text(),"Fecha Publicación:")]/ancestor::node()[1]/text()`